# Surface fitting through the least squares' general regression matrix formula.

Tags: numerical-methods, surfaces, regression, linear-regression

The last page of [this paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UCVB.png) attemps to fit a paraboloid to a set of given 3D points through the [general linear regression matrix formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UCVB.png) , my question here is to what extent is this approach valid? can I surface fit Z=a*f(x,y)+b*g(x,y)+c*h(x,y)+.... using the same approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $n$ data points$(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ and you want to fit a model
$$z=a+b x+c y+d x^2+e x y+ f y^2$$

Let us define $t_i=x^2_i$, $u_i=x_i y_i$ and $v_i=y_i^2$ which makes the model to be
$$z=a+bx+c y+d t+e u+f v$$ which is a multilinear regression model. Just write the classical matrix form and replace (if you want) the $(t,u,v)$ by their definition.

Comment: I wonder if I can do the same for Z=a*f(x,y)+b*g(x,y)+c*h(x,y)..... for some reason by searching online I can't find so much about this.

Comment: @Essam. For sure as long as the functions $f(x,y),g(x,y),h(x,y),\cdots)$ are explicit and do not contain any unknown parameter.

Comment: This is so analogous to how we dealt with it in 2D, thank you.

Comment: @Essam. It is not analogous. It is just the *same* ! Cheers :-)